# Import csv as list of list in python 3.3

Tags: python, list, csv, python-3.x, import

i hav a list of list with 2 strings and 1 integer

```
list_of_ee = [["a","m",15],["w","p",34]]
```

i export this to csv file using this code.

```
import csv

myfile = open("pppp.csv", 'wb')
with open("pppp.csv", "w",newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    wr.writerows(list_of_ee)
```

result was

```
a m 15
w p 34
```

and i export that using this code

```
data = csv.reader(open('pppp.csv','r', newline=''))
data = list(data)
print(data)
```

and the result was

```
[['a', 'm', '15'], ['w', 'p', '34']]
```

but I want to import this results same as it was (as list of list and with 2 str and 1 integer)(when my program restart)in `list_of_ee`
and I want to add them to `list_of_ee` (becoz when program starts there's no data in
`list_of_ee` .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export data from csv as a list(python 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557611/how-to-export-data-from-csv-as-a-listpython-3)

Comment: This might help : [How to convert list of elements to their default types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656498/how-to-convert-list-of-elements-to-their-default-types)

Comment: @kojiro ya i didnt got any good answrs from that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use CSV, you get strings.  See the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents

"No automatic data type conversion is performed."

@hcwhsa pointed you to an answer that shows how to use `ast.literal_eval()` to guess at the types.  It's not too hard:

```
import ast
import csv

def convert_type(s):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(s)
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
        return s

def convert_csv_row(lst):
    return [convert_type(x) for x in lst]

data = csv.reader(open('pppp.csv','r', newline=''))
converted = [convert_csv_row(row) for row in data]
print(converted)
```

But really, why are you even using CSV if you want to preserve the types?  Unless you are exporting data to a spreadsheet or something, I suggest you use JSON format.

```
import json

list_of_ee = [["a","m",15],["w","p",34]]

with open("test.json", "wt") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(list_of_ee))

with open("test.json", "rt") as f:
    s = f.read()
    lst = json.loads(s)

print(lst)
assert list_of_ee == lst
```

JSON is a great way to export data to other programs.

But if you are just trying to save data for your own Python programs, it's even easier: just use `pickle`.  http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

```
import pickle

list_of_ee = [["a","m",15],["w","p",34]]

with open("test.pickle", "wb") as f:
    f.write(pickle.dumps(list_of_ee))

with open("test.pickle", "rb") as f:
    bytes_data = f.read()
    lst = pickle.loads(bytes_data)

print(lst)
assert list_of_ee == lst
```

With `pickle` you need to write and read the file in binary mode, not text mode.  Also with `pickle` you can save pretty much any Python native type, not just the basic ones supported by JSON.  But pretty much only Python programs read a `pickle` file.

Comment: Don't forget `SyntaxError`. Strings like `'1abc'`, `'a bc'` if present will raise `SyntaxError`.

Comment: That means that the expression `list_of_ee == lst` did not evaluate true.  In other words, the restored list is not equal to the original list.  I suggest you print both lists, look at them, and figure out why they are different.  When I ran that program it worked for me.

Comment: I don't even understand what you just asked.  Are you asking if that `assert` would fire in your program?  You don't have to even put an `assert` statement.

Comment: first of all sry coz i didnt understood pickle .ya. i delete and tried.bt it wont (in my program) append data to my program's list?

Answer (score 1):

There's no CSV-builtin way of doing what you're asking, since the CSV format has no notion of datatypes; that is, it doesn't distinguish between a string and an integer.

You could `try` doing something like this:

```
for lst in list_of_ee:
    for i,l in enumerate(lst):
        try:
            lst[i] = int(l)
        except:
            pass
```

to convert numerical elements of your sublists into integers.

Comment: so ar there any other way of doing that?

Comment: If you don't like the `try`/`except` you could do this: `lst[i] = int(l) if l.isdigit() else l`